# Linking external logins to existing user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity-2

I'm quite new to `Identity` and trying to learn by watching videos in https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Customizing-ASPNET-Authentication-with-Identity

In the default ASP.Net MVC template, you can link multiple external logins (google, facebook) to your account (through `/Manage`) if you are already logged in.

But what if the user first logged in to our website using their google account and log out from it and on another day tried to login using their facebook account. Assuming both of their facebook and google accounts uses the same email address, the user will not be able to login to the website because the default template doesn't allow that as `UserManager.CreateAsync` is going to fail. I know they can change their email and login, but that will create two different accounts for the same user.

```
var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (info == null)
{
    return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
}
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

I altered the code in `ExternalLoginConfirmation` so that it checks if the user exist and ads the new external provider to `AspNetUserLogins`. Can anyone please tell me if this is the right way to do this? or if there is a better way of doing it.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the information about the user from the external login provider
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            //new code begins
            else if (UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email) != null)
            {
                var usr = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(usr.Id, info.Login);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(usr, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            //new code ends
            AddErrors(result);
        }
```

Comment: Did you confirm this is ideal way to handle this?

Comment: Nope, but this is how I'm using it at the moment for a project I'm working on. I've tried to ask this in Microsoft Virtual Academy forum as well. But unfortunately no answer yet.

Comment: I am currently in the same situation as you did.  I was thinking about doing it in the same way.  Could you please let us know if you found the better solution?

Comment: Not really, I posted this in numerous thread but didn't get a better answer.

Comment: I'm not convinced auto-linking external accounts based off matching email is a wise thing to do. Especially if you can also create a local account - I could use your email if you don't have email validation process enforced. And then when you sign into Facebook or Google, it links to my account on the matched email. Also, does matching email in Facebook and Google really, truly mean the same identity? How is this guaranteed?

Comment: @dapug I have the same doubt as well. I think there should be a step for verification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also fairly new to Identity and have come across the same problem, though my solution is quite different. I don't use Entity Framework and to achieve this I've had to basically rewrite the entire Identity engine with custom classes. I have my own Sql Server tables which are different to those created by EF. EF stores identity in 5 tables: users, roles, userroles, userclaims and userlogins. I only use the first three. In my environment AddLoginAsync is not required because the table doesn't exist. I store all local/external logins and registered users in the user table. Claims are stored as userroles when required.

The way I got around duplicate UserNames and Emails (logging in using different providers with the same registered email addresses) was to remove the validation check for existing usernames and emails before creating a user, using a custom UserValidator. The table allows for duplicates. When logging in I do a custom check for uniqueness based on username/provider (external) or email/passwordhash (local). It seems to be working.